# I am trying to 'build and run' a c++ project main.cpp and i get the following compiler error

Tags: c++

```
> Executing task: make run <

make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make run
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command make run" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Note: The `C:\minGW\bin` path is added in the `PATH` variable and all the mingw32-make packages are installed. What else could the problem be?

Comment: Perhaps try a regular command prompt instead of powershell.

Comment: Traditionally, one uses `make` until source file has no errors.  Then the executable file is run.  Then the debugger.

Comment: Go look in `C:\minGW\bin` and make sure you have `make` and not `mingw_make`, etc.. I have seen some MinGW implementations that prefix the commands.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile your code from Powershell?  `make` is not a Powershell command. It's a command line executable. You should be using a normal command prompt instead.